# measure of a set which is a subset of infinitely many subsets of probability measure space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $B,A_1,A_2,....$ be the subsets of a probability measure space. If $ B \subset \bigcup A_j$, show that $m(B) \le \sum_{j=0}^\infty m(A_j)$. I have no idea as how to approach it.

I do have the knowledge of axiom of countable additivity, but have no idea as how to approach this problem from that axiom.

Comment: $\mu(\cup_j A_j) = \mu(B) + \mu(B^C \cap (\cup_j A_j))$ so $\mu(B)=\mu(\cup_j A_j) -\mu(B^C \cap (\cup_j A_j)) \leq \sum_j \mu(A_j)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a general fact that if $\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable sets, then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ is also measurable, with 
$$ \mu\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\Big)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)$$
This property is sometimes called countable subadditivity.

One way to prove it is as follows: let $B_1=A_1$, and for $n>1$ let $B_n=A_n\setminus (\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k)$. Then the $B_n$ are pairwise disjoint with $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n$, hence by countable additivity
$$ \mu(\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\Big)=\mu\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\Big)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_n)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)$$
with the last inequality coming from the fact that $B_n\subset A_n$ for all $n$.

Finally, we can conclude that $\mu(B)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)$ for all $B\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ by monotonicity.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $m$ refers to probability

$$A \subset B \to P(A) \le P(B)$$

In our case we have $$P(B) \le P(\bigcup_j A_j)$$

We also have $$P(\bigcup_j A_j) \le \sum_j P(A_j)$$

by [countable subadditivity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Measure_is_Countably_Subadditive).